# Using greenDAO to map JSON String to object

Tags: android, json, orm, greendao, greendao-generator

I have this JSON response that I wish to map into my object:

```
{
    "title" : "Star Trek",
    "object_ids" : [
       "100",
       "101"
    ]
}
```

What I've done is created the one to many property in my main object, however I'm not sure how to map the string property that is without a key, and retrofit gives this error:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but found STRING.

My object mapping in my generator looks like this:

```
Entity movie = schema.addEntity("Movie");
movie.addStringProperty("title");

Entity objectIds = schema.addEntity("ObjectIds");
Property link = objectIds.addStringProperty("ids").getProperty(); // line 5

movie.addToMany(objectIds, link, "object_ids");
```

Obviously this is because in line 5, I am creating the property in a way that I expect it to be a value of the `"ids"` key, but what should I have put here instead?

Comment: what error is this retrofit or greendao?

Comment: it is because the response is not a valid JSON response, you should check your response that you pass to retrofit